# Struggling with Normalization values when training model

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to train an adversarial patch located at the bottom left corner of the image to cause a misclassification. Currently, I am using these parameters to normalize the CIFAR10 dataset.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.4914,0.4822,0.4465),(0.2023,0.1994,0.201))]
```

This would result in the images having a maximum and minimum value of around 2.55 and -2.55 respectively. However, I'm not sure how to work with this range when training my patch. I struggle between converting the patch from a range of (0,1) to (-2.55,2.55). Any help is appreciated!

My code for training is below: (I don't think its training properly for now)

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.models as models 
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torchattacks
import random
import torch.nn.functional as F


dictionary ={
    '0':'airplane',
    '1':'automobile',
    '2':'bird',
    '3':'cat',
    '4':'deer',
    '5':'dog',
    '6':'frog',
    '7':'horse',
    '8':'ship',
    '9':'truck',
    }
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.4914,0.4822,0.4465),(0.2023,0.1994,0.201))])
#transform1 = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
normalize = transforms.Normalize((0.4914,0.4822,0.4465),(0.2023,0.1994,0.201))
mean =(0.4914,0.4822,0.4465)
std =(0.2023,0.1994,0.201)
inv_normalize = transforms.Normalize(
    mean=[-0.4914/0.2023, -0.4822/0.1994, -0.4465/0.201],
    std=[1/0.2023, 1/0.1994, 1/0.201])
batch_size = 1

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
model = torch.hub.load("chenyaofo/pytorch-cifar-models", "cifar10_resnet20", pretrained=True)
model = model.cuda()
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'
patch = np.random.rand(3,32,32)
model.eval() 

def mask_generation(mask_type='rectangle', patch = patch, image_size=(3, 7, 7)):
    applied_patch = np.zeros(image_size) #0,1
    #patch = torch.tensor(patch)
    #padding = (3,3,3,3)
    #patch = F.pad(patch, padding)


    if mask_type == 'rectangle':
        rotation_angle = 0
        for i in range(patch.shape[0]):
            patch[i] = np.rot90(patch[i], rotation_angle)

        x_location , y_location = 25,0       
        
        
        for i in range(patch.shape[0]):
            applied_patch[:, x_location:x_location + patch.shape[1], y_location:y_location + patch.shape[2]] = patch
    mask = applied_patch.copy()
    mask[mask != 0] = 1.0  

    return patch , applied_patch, mask, x_location, y_location , rotation_angle  

def patch_attack(image, applied_patch, mask, target, probability_threshold, model, lr, max_iteration):  
    
    applied_patch = torch.from_numpy(applied_patch)
    mask = torch.from_numpy(mask) 
   
    image = inv_normalize(image)
    
    target_probability, count = 0,0
    perturbated_image = torch.mul(mask.type(torch.FloatTensor), applied_patch.type(torch.FloatTensor)) + torch.mul((1 - mask.type(torch.FloatTensor)), image.type(torch.FloatTensor)) 
    perturbated_image = normalize(perturbated_image)
    while target_probability < probability_threshold and count < max_iteration:
        count += 1
        # Optimize the patch
        perturbated_image = Variable(perturbated_image.data, requires_grad=True) 
        per_image = perturbated_image.cuda()
        output = model(per_image)
        target_log_softmax = torch.nn.functional.log_softmax(output, dim=1)[0][target]
        target_log_softmax.backward()
        patch_grad = perturbated_image.grad.clone().cpu()
        applied_patch = (lr * patch_grad) + applied_patch.type(torch.FloatTensor)
        applied_patch = torch.clamp(applied_patch,0,1)
        perturbated_image.grad.data.zero_()
        
        # Test the patch

        perturbated_image = torch.mul(mask.type(torch.FloatTensor), applied_patch.type(torch.FloatTensor)) + torch.mul((1-mask.type(torch.FloatTensor)), image.type(torch.FloatTensor)) 
        perturbated_image = normalize(perturbated_image)
        perturbated_image = perturbated_image.cuda()
        
        output = model(perturbated_image) 
        target_probability = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=1).data[0][target]
        
    perturbated_image = perturbated_image.detach().cpu().numpy()
    applied_patch = applied_patch.cpu().numpy()
    return perturbated_image, applied_patch

def test_patch(patch_type, target, patch, test_loader, model):
    test_total, test_actual_total, test_success = 0, 0, 0
    for (image, label) in test_loader:
        test_total += label.shape[0]
        assert image.shape[0] == 1, 'Only one picture should be loaded each time.'
        image = image.cuda() #-3,3
        label = label.cuda()
        output = model(image)
        _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        if predicted[0] != label and predicted[0].data.cpu().numpy() != target:
            test_actual_total += 1
            patch ,applied_patch, mask, x_location, y_location =  mask_generation('rectangle', patch, (3, 32, 32))
            applied_patch = torch.from_numpy(applied_patch) 
            
            mask = torch.from_numpy(mask) 
            mask = normalize(mask)
            applied_patch = normalize(applied_patch)
            
            perturbated_image = torch.mul(mask.type(torch.FloatTensor), applied_patch.type(torch.FloatTensor)) + torch.mul((1 - mask.type(torch.FloatTensor)), image.type(torch.FloatTensor))
            perturbated_image = perturbated_image.cuda() #-3,3
            
            output = model(perturbated_image)
            _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
            if predicted[0].data.cpu().numpy() == target:
                test_success += 1
    return test_success / test_actual_total

#training parameters
epochs = 1
target = 0 
probability_threshold = 0.99
lr = 1/255
max_iteration = 1

runs = 0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    train_total, train_actual_total, train_success = 0, 0, 0
    for (image, label) in trainloader:
        runs+=1
        
        
        assert image.shape[0] == 1
        image = image.cuda()  
        label = label.cuda()
        train_total += label.shape[0]
        output = model(image)
        _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
        if predicted[0] != label or predicted[0].data.cpu().numpy() != target:
            train_actual_total += 1

            patch , applied_patch, mask, x_location, y_location ,rotation_angle = mask_generation('rectangle', patch, (3, 32, 32))       
            
            perturbated_image, applied_patch = patch_attack(image, applied_patch, mask, target, probability_threshold, model, lr,max_iteration)
            perturbated_image = torch.from_numpy(perturbated_image).cuda()
            output = model(perturbated_image)
            _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
            if predicted[0].data.cpu().numpy() == target:
                train_success += 1
                
            patch = applied_patch[0][:, x_location:x_location + patch.shape[1], y_location:y_location + patch.shape[2]]
            patch = np.array(patch)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number `x` in the range [0,1] to the range [-2.55,2.55]:

1. Multiply by `size of final range` / `size of original range` or in this case 5.1/1.0.
2. Add `min of final range` - `min of starting range` to the result, so in this case -2.55+0 = 0.